# How to get UITableView row when user taps on UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift

**App Scheme-**

[image]

As you can see from my App Scheme I have `UITableView` and inside `UITableViewCells` I have `UICollectionView`.

My question right now is how to get `UITableView` row when user taps on `UICollectionViewCell`?

I tried this but that doesn't work me:

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)

    let main = ViewController()
    if let tableViewcell = superview?.superview as? ExploreTableViewCell {
        let indexPath = main.tableView.indexPath(for: tableViewcell)
        
        
        print(indexPath)
    }
}
```

Comment: If it’s your own UICollectionView, why not you have the row index as a field in it and populate it in item for row at index function of UITableView?

Comment: Hey there. On mobile, but comment here and I’ll upload my code for a collection view inside a table view cell tomorrow!

Comment: Move out table view from collections, don't mix them. I'm certain that you can refactor this code in a way easier to handle. I never seen a collection with tables and I don't think it works at all.

Comment: @JBarros35 My CollectionView is in TableViewCell and not vice versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To an extension of Subramanian Mariappan's concept and using `delegate` pattern to get informed in `UIViewController` about selection in collection view cell, please check your solution at https://github.com/sauvikapple/StackoverflowQ63802523.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Refactoring this viewController is on my todo list, but this should help out.

The key is `setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate()` inside of `willDisplayCell()`. This lets you tap into the cell, and into the collectionView. And you can do something like set the tag to the row number.

TableView Cell:

```
import UIKit

class CollectionViewInsideTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        
        collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "cellNibName", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cellIdentifier")
    }
    
    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        
    }
    
    func setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate(dataSourceDelegate: UICollectionViewDataSource & UICollectionViewDelegate, forSection section: Int, multipleSelection: Bool) {
        collectionView.delegate = dataSourceDelegate
        collectionView.dataSource = dataSourceDelegate
        collectionView.allowsSelection = true // If Needed
        collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = multipleSelection // If Needed
        
        collectionView.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(item: 31, section: 0), at: .right, animated: false)
        self.collectionView.layoutSubviews()
    }
    
}
```

Implementation:

```
cellforRow() {
    let collectionCell = CollectionViewInsideTableViewCell // ETC
    return collectionCell
}


extension TableViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        guard let tableViewCell = cell as? CollectionViewInsideTableViewCell else { return }
        tableViewCell.setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate(dataSourceDelegate: self, forSection: indexPath.section, multipleSelection: true)
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        
        let cell = CollectionViewCell // ETC
        return cell
    }
```